# On connectedness of intersection of subgroups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, intersection-theory

I am quite interested in any partical answer to the following general (maybe a little bit vague) question: Is there some criterion about the connectedness of the intersection of two connected algebraic subgroups of a linear algebraic subgroup defined over a perfect field?

Indeed, the general question is motivated by the following special case of it: 
Let $G$ be a semisimple group defined over $k$, which is the algebraic closure of a finite field. Let $U\subset G$ be a connected unipotent subgroup and $H\subset G$ be a parabolic (or any connected) subgroup, then is $U\cap H$ is still connected?

Any comments are very welcome! Thanks in advance!

Comment: In general, I think you're out of luck.  (However, perhaps one could handle the case where $U$ is the unipotent radical of a parabolic, and hence filtered by $\mathfrak{gl}_1$'s, and that such groups have no smooth, finite subgroups?)  It may be of interest to know Proposition 14.22(a) of Borel, which states that the intersection of two parabolics is connected; that seems close to your situation.

Comment: Also intersection with Levi subgroups of reductive groups often behaves well, as one shows using the fact they are centralisers of tori.

Answer (score 4):

Let $p=\mathrm{char}\,k$ and $G=GL(3,k)$. Then
$$
\{\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\t-t^p&1&t\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\mid t\in k\}
$$
is a group isomorphic to $\mathbf{G}_a$. Its intersection with the Borel subgroup of upper triangular matrices is $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Usually, the connectedness of $U\cap P$ is shown by exhibiting a torus which normalizes both $U$ and $P$ and whose action on $U$ is contracting.

Comment: Just to be clear, that's the discrete group $\mathbb F_p$, not the group $\mathbf G_a$, even if it happens that $k = \mathbb F_p$.

Comment: (Err, I mean "the constant group scheme $\mathbb F_p$".)